# When I recreate machine learning model in flask api, the server shuts down without any warning

Tags: python, machine-learning, flask

```
from flask import Blueprint, request, current_app as app
from project_app.modules import ml_tool, pickle_tool


adminBp = Blueprint('admin', __name__, url_prefix='/admin')

@adminBp.route('/refresh', methods=['POST'])
def refresh():
    body = request.get_json()
    
    df_nonTest, df_test = ml_tool.get_splitted_df()
    app.models = ml_tool.create_models(df_nonTest) # Shutdown occured when this file contain this line.
    pickle_tool.save_models(app.models)
    print('model is created') 
    app.score = ml_tool.create_roc_auc_score(df_test, app.models) # No shutdown occured even this file contains this line.
    pickle_tool.save_score(app.score)
    print('score is calculated')

    return {'message' : 'refreshed'}, 200
```

and output is like this

```
...
Batch 8 started...
[0]     validation_0-auc:0.67508
[107]   validation_0-auc:0.77892
Batch 9 started...
[0]     validation_0-auc:0.68782
[102]   validation_0-auc:0.78389
model is created
score is calculated
127.0.0.1 - - [01/May/2023 01:26:21] "POST /admin/refresh HTTP/1.1" 200 -
(an_env) 
user@computer MINGW64 /path/to/project (main)
$
```

I could see 'model is created', and 'score is calculated' printed.
And I could get response of 'refreshed' but after then, the server shuts down without any error or warning. Can somebody explain why this happened and what can be the right code if you can?

Comment: Nothing in this code shuts the server down

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. You say that it gives the full printout, but you have `app.models = ml_tool.create_models(df_nonTest)` listed as apparently shutting the server down - in which case, you'd never get the second printout. Whatever is happening isn't shown

Comment: I said, if this file contain that first commented line then the server shuts down. I didn't say the error occured at that first commented line